# Regex Help for wildcard lookup

Tags: sql, regex, database, psql

I am having issues with this wildcard lookup, not sure why this doesn't work:

I am looking up example Sales Agent 42. As you can imagine being sales, they do not really care about garbage in = garbage out. So their agent codes are usually a mess to sort through.

Valid Examples for Agent 42:

- **42**
- 30-**42**-22-holiday
- **42**easter
- **42**-coupon
- **42**coupon-423355
- 29-**42**sale-52

Non-Valid Examples that explicitly need to not show up

- A**42**900**42**
- **42**97901
- **42**cmowc209d
- o203f9j**42**po0

Here is the most successful model I came up with:

```
SELECT company_id, agent
FROM cust_data
WHERE (agent = ('42') OR agent LIKE ('42%-%') OR agent LIKE ('%-%42') OR agent LIKE ('%-%42%-%') OR agent LIKE ('42[a-z]%-%') OR agent LIKE ('%-%42[a-z]%') OR agent LIKE ('%-%42[a-z]%-%') OR agent LIKE ('42[a-z]%'))
```

I get most of the valid ones to return and none of the non-valid ones, but I still can't seem to grab the examples like **42**easter or 29-**42**sale-52 even though I am telling it to grab that style...

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about just `agent ~ '(^|[^0-9])42($|[^0-9])'`?

Comment: well that worked wonderfully. did not know about the "^" symbol, would be more efficient to exclude numerics than look for only alpha's. Many thanks!

Comment: I posted although I am a bit puzzled by your `42cmowc209d` and `o203f9j42po0` examples

Comment: those were examples i would get sometimes that needed to be excluded or not counted in the look up. sometimes the sales throws in random codes that just coincidentally have their agent code thrown in. They are few and easy to spot in the outputs so i think i might just have to live with hand pulling those...

Comment: Yeah, those can only be excluded by a human then.

Comment: unfortunately so, but your solution helped immensely. very simple and elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you need to match `42` that is not surrounded with digits**, you can use alternations with *anchors* (`^` standing for the start of string and `$` standing for the end of string) and *negated character classes*:

```
WHERE agent ~ '(^|[^0-9])42($|[^0-9])'
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP7kF1/1)

Explanation:

- `(^|[^0-9])` - either the start of the string `^` or a non-digit `[^0-9]`
- `42` - literal `42`
- `($|[^0-9])` - end of string `$` or a non-digit `[^0-9]`